# Fastest way to copy data from ReadOnlySpan to output with pixel conversion

Tags: c#, memory-management, uwp

I'm having performance issue when I copy the data from input **(ReadOnlySpan)** to output **(Span)** using (Loops like 'for')

there is **Span.CopyTo**, it's perfect and very fast
but for now it's useless without converting the pixels.

below is the code, I have feeling that there is some short way to do that instead of the current process:

```
public unsafe void UpdateFromOutput(CanvasDevice device, ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, uint width, uint height, uint pitch)
{
  using (var renderTargetMap = new BitmapMap(device, RenderTarget))
  {
   var inputPitch = (int)pitch;
   var mapPitch = (int)renderTargetMap.PitchBytes;
                       
   var mapData = new Span<byte>(new  IntPtr(renderTargetMap.Data).ToPointer(), (int)RenderTarget.Size.Height * mapPitch);

   switch (CurrentPixelFormat)
   {
    case PixelFormats.RGB0555:
      FramebufferConverter.ConvertFrameBufferRGB0555ToXRGB8888(width, height, data, inputPitch, mapData, mapPitch);
    break;

    case PixelFormats.RGB565:
      FramebufferConverter.ConvertFrameBufferRGB565ToXRGB8888(width, height, data, inputPitch, mapData, mapPitch);
    break; 
   }

  }
}
```

then inside function like **ConvertFrameBufferRGB0555ToXRGB8888**

I will go through width and height like below:

```
var castInput = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ushort>(input);
var castInputPitch = inputPitch / sizeof(ushort);
var castOutput = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, uint>(output);
var castOutputPitch = outputPitch / sizeof(uint);
castOutput.Fill(0);

 for (var i = 0; i < height;i++)
 {
   var inputLine = castInput.Slice(i * castInputPitch, castInputPitch);
   var outputLine = castOutput.Slice(i * castOutputPitch, castOutputPitch);

    for (var j = 0; j < width;j++)
    {
     outputLine[j] = ConverToRGB888(inputLine[j]);
    }
 }
```

The code above working but slow in some cases.

**Please note:** I'm modifying a project so the code above was written by the original developer and I need help because I don't understand how the process is working, still very confused.. specially in the **Slice** part.

Tried as **test only** to copy the input to output directly `data.CopyTo(mapData);` and I got this (as expected):
[image]

Hope there is some solution with Marshal and Span functions

Many thanks.

**Update regarding (ConverToRGB888)**

As for ConverToRGB888, the original code contains **RGB565LookupTable**:

```
private const uint LookupTableSize = ushort.MaxValue + 1;
private static uint[] RGB565LookupTable = new uint[LookupTableSize];

public static void SetRGB0565LookupTable()
{
  uint r565, g565, b565;

  double red = 255.0;
  double green = 255.0;
  double blue = 255.0;

  for (uint i = 0; i < LookupTableSize; i++)
  {
     //RGB565
     r565 = (i >> 11) & 0x1F;
     g565 = (i >> 5) & 0x3F;
     b565 = (i & 0x1F);

     r565 = (uint)Math.Round(r565 * red / 31.0);
     g565 = (uint)Math.Round(g565 * green / 63.0);
     b565 = (uint)Math.Round(b565 * blue / 31.0);

     RGB565LookupTable[i] = (0xFF000000 | r565 << 16 | g565 << 8 | b565);
   }
}

private static uint ConverToRGB888(ushort x)
{
  return RGB565LookupTable[x];
}
```

**SetRGB0565LookupTable()** will be called only once to fill the values.

### Conclusion:

- The `Fill(0)` was not important and it was causing delay
- The unsafe version **(accepted answer)** was clear for me and a bit faster
- Avoiding `For` partially even faster like [Here](https://github.com/basharast/RetrixGold/blob/main/src/RetriX.Shared/Components/CrazyBufferMove.cs) [Tested]
- Pre-Lookup table is very helpful and made the conversion faster
- Memory helpers like `Span.CopyTo`, `Buffer.MemoryCopy` source available [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Span.cs)
- Using `Parallel.For` is faster in some cases with help of [UnsafeMemory](https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/main/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/UnsafeMemory.cs)
- If you have input with (Pixels Type) supported by **Win2D** there is possibility to avoid loops like:

```
byte[] dataBytes = new byte[data.Length];
fixed (byte* inputPointer = &data[0])
Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)inputPointer, dataBytes, 0, data.Length);
RenderTarget = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(renderPanel, dataBytes, (int)width, (int)height, DirectXPixelFormat.R8G8UIntNormalized, 92, CanvasAlphaMode.Ignore);
```

but not sure from the last point as I wasn't able to test on 565,555.

Thanks for **DekuDesu** the explanation and simplified version he provide helped me to do more tests.

Comment: Please try indenting your code. It will make it easier to read.

Comment: Can we see the definition and implementation of `ConverToRGB888`?

Comment: @DekuDesu I have RGB565/RGB555 input and I need to send it to the output as RGB888 with any possible way but with less loops.

Comment: @DekuDesu I updated the code and added **ConverToRGB888**, I'm looking for solution using Marshal and Span.CopyTo with maximum one 'Loop' if that is possible.

Comment: Well it looks like you're just converting each pixel from RGB565/555 to RGB88, and you have two `for` loops. This is O(n) with your lookups being O(1). There is no improvement there unless you skip pixels. The next *possible* option would be to avoid slicing all together, which would give you marginal improvements at best. You could try manually processing the bytes instead of Marshall.cast<> bit doing so would be using **unsafe** byte manipulation. Which would probably save you some copies in memory at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having performance issue when I copy the data from input (ReadOnlySpan) to output (Span) using (Loops like 'for')

The the code you provided is already pretty safe and has the best complexity you're going get for pixel-by-pixel operations. The presence of nested `for` loops does not necessarily correspond to performance issues or increased complexity.

> I need help because I don't understand how the process is working, still very confused.. specially in the Slice part.

This code looks like it's meant to convert one bitmap format to another. Bitmaps come in varying sizes and formats. Because of this they include an additional piece of information along with width and height, pitch.

Pitch is the distance **in bytes** between two lines of pixel information, this is used to account for formats that don't include full 32/64bit color information.

Knowing this I commented the method in question as to help explain what it's doing.

```cs
public static void ConvertFrameBufferRGB565ToXRGB8888(uint width, uint height, ReadOnlySpan<byte> input, int inputPitch, Span<byte> output, int outputPitch)
{
    // convert the span of bytes into a span of ushorts
    // so we can use span[i] to get a ushort
    var castInput = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ushort>(input);

    // pitch is the number of bytes between the first byte of a line and the first byte of the next line
    // convert the pitch from bytes into ushort pitch
    var castInputPitch = inputPitch / sizeof(ushort);

    // convert the span of bytes into a span of ushorts
    // so we can use span[i] to get a ushort
    var castOutput = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, uint>(output);
    var castOutputPitch = outputPitch / sizeof(uint);

    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // get a line from the input
        // remember that pitch is the number of ushorts between lines
        // so i * pitch here gives us the index of the i'th line, and we don't need the padding
        // ushorts at the end so we only take castInputPitch number of ushorts
        var inputLine = castInput.Slice(i * castInputPitch, castInputPitch);
                
        // same thing as above but for the output
        var outputLine = castOutput.Slice(i * castOutputPitch, castOutputPitch);

        for (var j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // iterate through the line, converting each pixel and storing it in the output span
            outputLine[j] = ConverToRGB888(inputLine[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

> Fastest way to copy data from ReadOnlySpan to output with pixel conversion

Honestly the method you provided is just fine, it's safe and fast ish. Keep in mind that copying data like bitmaps linearly on CPU's is an inherently slow process. The most performance savings you could hope for is avoiding copying data redundantly. Unless this needs absolutely blazing speed I would not recommend changes other than removing `.fill(0)` since it's probably unnecessary, but you would have to test that.

If you **ABSOLUTELY** must get more performance out of this you may want to *consider* something like what I've provided below. I caution you however, unsafe code like this is well.. **unsafe** and is prone to errors. It has almost no error checking and makes a LOT of assumptions, so that's up for you to implement.

If it's still not fast enough consider writing a .dll in C and use interop maybe.

```cs
public static unsafe void ConvertExtremelyUnsafe(ulong height, ref byte inputArray, ulong inputLength, ulong inputPitch, ref byte outputArray, ulong outputLength, ulong outputPitch)
{
    // pin down pointers so they dont move on the heap
    fixed (byte* inputPointer = &inputArray, outputPointer = &outputArray)
    {
        // since we have to account for padding we should go line by line
        for (ulong y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            // get a pointer for the first byte of the line of the input
            byte* inputLinePointer = inputPointer + (y * inputPitch);

            // get a pointer for the first byte of the line of the output
            byte* outputLinePointer = outputPointer + (y * outputPitch);

            // traverse the input line by ushorts
            for (ulong i = 0; i < (inputPitch / sizeof(ushort)); i++)
            {
                // calculate the offset for the i'th ushort,
                // becuase we loop based on the input and ushort we dont need an index check here
                ulong inputOffset = i * sizeof(ushort);

                // get a pointer to the i'th ushort
                ushort* rgb565Pointer = (ushort*)(inputLinePointer + inputOffset);

                ushort rgb565Value = *rgb565Pointer;

                // convert the rgb to the other format
                uint rgb888Value = ConverToRGB888(rgb565Value);

                // calculate the offset for i'th uint
                ulong outputOffset = i * sizeof(uint);

                // at least attempt to avoid overflowing a buffer, not that the runtime would let you do that, i would hope..
                if (outputOffset >= outputLength)
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(outputArray)}[{outputOffset}]");
                }

                // get a pointer to the i'th uint
                uint* rgb888Pointer = (uint*)(outputLinePointer + outputOffset);

                // write the bytes of the rgb888 to the output array
                *rgb888Pointer = rgb888Value;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

*disclaimer*: I wrote this on mobile

Comment: Brilliant solution, the unsafe function gives better performance, I really appreciate your explanation it's now more clear to me many thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how much performance gain did you get? I was too lazy to actually set this up to convert a bitmap so I just estimated this at like 10-15% faster due to no memory copies.

Comment: I'm enhancing games emulator, and I went into unexpected frame drop from 60fps to 30~37fps (after I implemented pixels cache/skip solution).. with your unsafe version back to normal at 60fps, your method is pure mathematical and I never trusted Microsoft extensions .CopyTo, Slice..etc.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got a non-marginal improvement! It should be noted however, the .NET Runtime, despite having MS's name slapped on it is just developed by chaps like me. You can check out the source code for `Span` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Span.cs). Interestingly enough it looks like their implementation of `.Slice()` is basically what I already wrote in this answer, I'm curious why there is a performance difference. Likely stack frame overhead or an issue with `Mashall.As<>`.

Comment: Thanks for the important info, will check `Span` code soon, btw I was able to use the pointers into `Parallel.For` with `List<Task>`  with help of [UnsafeMemory](https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/main/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/UnsafeMemory.cs). I got good results as it's not linear process anymore. do you think it's good idea or it's hardware consuming, anyway it's optional choice as I don't know how good this solution is.

Comment: No clue! If it works and it's faster then it's viable on my book. Just make sure it's **deterministic** in it's results.